# Search model with time range substitution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

One can search the model with time range like this:

```
User.where(updated_at: previous_update..now)
```

However I need a more complex query:

```
User.where("updated_at = :updated_at and status != :status",
            updated_at: previous_update..now, status: "employee")
```

And it turns out that

```
User.where("updated_at = :updated_at", updated_at: previous_update..now)
```

doesn't work. Looks like `previous_update..now` should be somehow translated to sql format before it can be substituted like this. Or maybe there's a better way to express the complex query above?

**Edit**

I used the [Jon's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35259761/788700) to chain `where` filters:

```
now     = Time.now
updates = User.where(updated_at: previous_update..now)

employee_updates     = updates.where(status: "employee")
non_employee_updates = updates.where('status != :status', status: "employee")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either chain your `where` queries:

```
User.where(status: 'employee').where(updated_at: previous_update..now)
```

Or you can combine them within the same `where` clause:

```
User.where(status: 'employee', updated_at: previous_update..now)
```

With your placeholder conditions, you need to wrap them in curly braces:

```
User.where('updated_at = :updated_at and status != :status', 
           {updated_at: previous_update, status: "employee"})
```

Although you can't check equality against a date range, so checking `updated_at` is equal to `previous_update..now` will fail. You'd need to generate the various conditions for being greater than or equal to the start date and less than or equal to the end date.

Based on that ... I'd probably stick with the non-placeholder format for a simple query like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
User.where("updated_at >= :updated_at", updated_at: previous_update)
```

if you need till now...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my current application I wanted to know the `now` exactly. But this approach might work in another situation.